# Firebase Login is not working properly in android

Tags: android, firebase

I am using the "FirebaseAuth" in Android. By using of "signInWithEmailAndPassword" I login inside firebase. And then I want to retrieve data from data base.
I able to log in but if I run "FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()" this code it return null. 
I am thanking to you if you suggest any solution.

```
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword("my_email08@gmail.com","qwerty123").addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this, "signInWithEmailAndPassword Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
               // startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
               //         SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
               Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this, "Not Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this," Login " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                displayChatMessages();
            }


        }
    });
```

I always get not Login in Toast.

Comment: take a eye on *Task<AuthResult> task* debug this.. may this help you.

Comment: Did you enable email sign-in from the console? Also, please provide a stacktrace from `task.getException()`.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion I got the error using the task.getException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Login or Not

```
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UploadActivity.class));
        finish();
        }
```

Login firebase.

```
         FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword("my_email08@gmail.com","qwerty123").addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this, "signInWithEmailAndPassword Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
           // startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),
           //         SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
           Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this, "Not Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(LiveVieoWatch.this," Login " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        }


    }
});
```